# Uma pequena mudança que faria diferença na sinalização

Tags: bug, status-pronto, sinalização

Em qualquer pergunta ou resposta, quando é feita uma sinalização, o que aparece na mensagem é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No que eu entendi, na mensagem diz que **vão analisar a pergunta**, não eu. A palavra "pergunta" é um substantivo feminino, e, portanto, deveria ser algo como *"Obrigado, vamos analisá-la"* ao invés de *"-lo"*.

Comment: Aos meus olhos PTpt faz todo o sentido corrigir. Pelo menos é isso que faço: analizo __a__ pergunta :)

Comment: Ou analiza a sinalização, de qualquer forma tem que corrigir.

Comment: Obrigado, vamos analisá-la

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mudança feita.

Como de costume, vai pro ar no próximo build.

Comment: Valeu, ajudou. :D